# How to set DCOM identity to The Launching User

Tags: batch-file, cmd, dcom

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\%APPID% /v RunAs /d %USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%
```

if I want to set DCOM properties (the identity tab) from "%USERDOMAIN%\%USERNAME%" to **"the launching user**", is it possible and how to do that? please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing. You need to delete RunAs.

Interactive User is for Interactive user. Absense of anything is the launching user.